# How does this Boolean simplification work?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I've just started learning about Boolean identities and simplification, and I'm already puzzled by one rule. I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/chpt-7/boolean-rules-for-simplification/), which presents the following rule:

```
A + AB = A
```

The proof is as follows:

```
A + AB
  ↓         Factoring A out of both terms
A(1 + B)
  ↓         Applying identity A + 1 = 1
A(1)
  ↓         Applying identity 1A = A
  A
```

I understand the second and third steps. B + 1 must be equivalent to 1 because if one input to an OR gate is 1, the output will always be 1. And the third step makes sense too, because whether 1 x A evaluates to 1 or 0 depends on the value of A.

What I don't understand is the first step. It's been many years since I've studied algebra at school, and the intuitive leap that "factoring A out of both terms" leads from `A + AB` to `A(1 + B)` is beyond my rusty skills.

I would greatly appreciate an explanation to help my understanding of how you "factor out" a Boolean variable for an equation, and how I would know to do this for any given equation.

Comment: Can you see it's true for integer (not boolean) arithmetic? That might help seeing it's true for boolean arithmetic too.

Comment: I guess so. 2 + (2 * 4) = 2 + 8 = 10, and 2 * (1 + 4) = 2 * 5 = 10. So it makes sense when you check it, I'm just not sure how I would determine that I need to change `A + AB` to A(1 + B) in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

It's just an identity. It's true. You can do that straight away.
A + AB = A(1 + B)

More generally:
AC + AB = A(C+B)

In this case, the boolean algebra identity is similar to what you usually do in normal algebra.

I don't think there is any proof for this except you can verify this with a truth table.

And I think there is a simpler and more intuitive way to perform this simplification in one step instead of three. If you consider AB, it can only be true if A is true. If A is false, then AB is also false. So if A is true, then A + AB is obviously true. And if A is false, then A + AB is also false.

So with this understanding, we can directly say A + AB = A

Comment: Well, what I don't get is why removing the second "A" from "AB" leads to there being a 1, and not a 0, or A, or anything else? I'm sure this is involving basic algebra, but I haven't done any such in coming up 10 years now, and I'm pretty rusty.

Comment: @Lou A·1 = A, right? A·0 = 0, so it's not the same.

Comment: @Hearth I'm probably just understanding this in a janky way (and/or tired at the end of a work day), but none of the answers have really helped me to understand the algebra going on here. I'm still confused by what exactly is happening when you change A + AB into A(1 + B). Are you ... dividing by A or something? And getting 1? I would be grateful for an ELI5 here.

Comment: @Lou Yes, dividing by A is a good analogy.

Comment: So, correct me if I'm misunderstanding ... it seems like if you "divide" A + AB by A, then you take the first A away and leave it with nothing. But you can't have nothing in Boolean terms, so you're left with a 1. You also take the second away from the "A and B" clause, but because there's a B left, you're left with B. So if you factor out A, that's why you get 1 and B inside the brackets. Am I anywhere near?

Answer (score 1):

\$xy+xz = x(y+z) \$ is known as the **distributive posulate** (OR-version).

In your case: \$A \cdot1+AB=A(1+B)=A \$

### From the comments

> So this is what I didn't get - why do you make A into A . 1? How do you "know" that there's a hidden "and 1" in that expression

This  is known as **posulate 2** of Boolean algebra: \$x \cdot1=x \$

Testing this postulate by plugging in \$x=0 \$ and \$x=1\$ proves its validity.
$$0 \cdot1=0 \: \: \: \text{for} \: \:x=0$$
$$1 \cdot1=1 \: \: \: \text{for} \: \:x=1$$

> And moreover, why is it 1? Not 0, or A?

If it was 0 then the Boolean equation would be false.
$$A \cdot1 \neq A \cdot0 $$
Actually, the expression \$x \cdot0=0 \$ is known as **theorem 2** of Boolean Algebra.

Comment: So this is what I didn't get - why do you make A into A . 1? How do you "know" that there's a hidden "and 1" in that expression, that only reveals itself when you factor out A? And moreover, why is it 1? Not 0, or A?

Comment: @Lou I edited my answer and added further explanations.

Comment: I have to admit that I'm still confused by this, sadly. I've studied the postulates A . 1 = A, A . 0 = 0 etc., and those make sense on their own. What I still don't really understand is what's happening when you take A + AB and convert it into A(1 + B). I don't have the mathematical knowledge to intuitively grasp what's happening - is this akin to division, or what? I think I just need an explanation as if I was a schoolchild.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it needs to go so far.

The first equation A+AB is true, if either A is true, or, A and B are both true.

So if B is true, A needs to be true too for the equation to be true. But the equation is true also when only A is true regardless of if B is true or not.